What's the name of the real size clon/golem of Percival?
Percival has a real size clon/golem who in the spanish sub he calls him "Punisibal". But I google that name and nothing appears.
What's the name of the real size clon/golem of Percival? He appears in episode 11 of the anime Nanatsu no taizai mokushiroku no yonkishi.
